# Youtube API returns wrong total results with search

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API with PHP to list videos of a channel in youtube, I have done it, paginated it and it works as well, and it returns me also de amount of videos that contain matching the terms, in the case, null.
Until this question it worked.

But...
if I use q= specified, it returns me the correct result, but the  of the XML returns me more than the query really has!

In the example:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/PREFEITURABQSC/uploads?orderby=updated&v=2&max-results=20&start-index=1&q=MARCOS I obtain 1 result. It is the correct. But the bugged YouTube API says me that have 30 in that channel!

If I go there to YouTube, it just have 1 matching, but shows me 30, with absolutely no relation!

My XML result is:

Check the link to see the XML: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/PREFEITURABQSC/uploads?orderby=updated&v=2&max-results=20&start-index=1&q=MARCOS

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total results is for helping, but does not always show exact number. Especially when you use filters, it's just an estimate.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere, that totalResults is an estimate?